# A JavaScript quirk I do not understand. looping through an array of objects

Tags: javascript

For the sake of brevity, I will keep the situation short.

I am loop through an object and I need to find possible duplicates of
the time.  An example of the data set is below:

```
let showList = [ 
    { name: 'Little Death Club', time: 8, length: 2, price: 10 },
    { name: 'Courtney Act', time: 6, length: 1, price: 10},
    { name: 'Reversible', time: 7, length: 1, price: 12 }
]
```

Basically I am getting an error with the following: I am looping
through the array of objects and have a conditional which is below.
The conditional is meant to find possible duplicate times:

```
showList[i + 1].time)  -->>  This throws an error.

showList[i].time)  -->> However this works.

showList[i + 1])  -->> AND this works...
```

I simply cannot understand why the first conditional doesn't work when
the other ones do.  I need the first one to work to complete my
problem.

Thanks for the help.:)

Comment: What are you using to loop through? forEach loop, do...while loop, for...in loop, for...of loop? Possibly, `showList[i+1]` is undefined, because your i is too big, so accessing .time throws the error

Comment: none of those can works ... since `showList[i + 1].time)` isn't even valid syntax

Comment: "I am looping through the array" - you should show us your code - we can't debug code we can't see. That said, I can guess that the loop stop condition is `i < array.length` which means there's no item at `showList[i + 1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to access the value of `showList[i + 1].time` in the loop you will throw a error because showList[i + 1] will be undefined on the last iteration and the property time of something `undefined` throws you a error

In the last case, `showList[i + 1]` it's just `undefined` but it's not breaking

I think your problem it's the `i + 1`, it doesn't exists on the last iteration

Comment: I think you are exactly right about this.  Thanks so much.  I didn't consider this before.  Thanks a million!!

Comment: Can you mark the answer as the correct one if it satisfy you?

Answer (score 0):

You could sort and reduce it.

[Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

[Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let showList = [
    { name: 'Little Death Club', time: 8, length: 2, price: 10 },
    { name: 'Courtney Act', time: 6, length: 1, price: 10 },
    { name: 'Reversible', time: 7, length: 1, price: 12 },
    { name: 'Test', time: 7, length: 1, price: 12 }
].sort((a, b) => a.time - b.time).reduce((acc, cur, idx, arr) => {
    let prev = arr[idx - 1];
    if (prev && prev.time === cur.time)
        acc.push(prev, cur);
    return acc;
}, []);
console.log(showList);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//showList[i + 1].time)
undefined
//showList[i].time)
undefined
//showList[i + 1])
undefined
let showList = [ 
    { name: 'Little Death Club', time: 8, length: 2, price: 10 },
    { name: 'Courtney Act', time: 6, length: 1, price: 10},
    { name: 'Reversible', time: 7, length: 1, price: 12 }
]

undefined
showList[i + 1].time)
VM194:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
showList[i].time)
VM197:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
showList[i + 1])
VM200:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

showList[i + 1].time
VM1049:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'time' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:1:17
(anonymous) @ VM1049:1
showList[i].time
VM1061:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'time' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:1:13
(anonymous) @ VM1061:1
showList[i]
undefined
i
undefined
```

Comment: What is this supposed to be?

Comment: Just use it like a law, @Greg